# Is it possible (How) to give compiler directives inside c/c++ code

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization

I would like my source code to give specific compiler directives (like remove symbols, speed optimization, stack frame sizes etc).

Just like `#pragma comment(lib, "Mylibrary.lib")`   gives a command to linker to include a given library I wonder if I can do something like

```
#if (__APPLE__)||(__ANDROID__)
/I"..\mobile\headers"
 -fvisibility=hidden -s 
#elif (WIN32)
 -O3
#endif
```

Meaning (activate -O3 optimization for windows32, while for mobile phones hide some symbols and include specific headers).

I can do it using Make Files or Visual studio projects but I wonder if it can be done within the source code to make it more platform and IDE independent

P.s. I understand that directives need to be matched to each specific compiler (gcc, LLVM, microsoft,...) and platform

Comment: Probably/Possibly. It'll be compiler specific though, so which compiler?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the code and not with a tool like Scons or CMake? That allows OS independant compilation without cluttering your sources with _compilation_ stuff.

Comment: Not an answer: No, you can't. You *will have* to rely on your build system for this. However, if you don't want to rely on a platform-specific build system, you have a few alternatives: scons/waf, CMake are the most popular.

Comment: For GCC compiler you can use "#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)" to hide the file symbols. https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: this is really compiler specific; I have seen compilers (for DSPs) that allow you to pass all sorts of info to the compiler (including what opt level to use on a specific file) but there is no common way of doing this except in the makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You can (to a degree) add pragma comments that will influence a compiler (for example, the pragma lib you showed).

Such a solution would be limited by compiler-specific support for pragmas.

Keeping such instructions in header files is a bad decision, because having to edit a code file, to change the build system settings is bad for maintenance.

If you split settings in a single file for multiple compilers, you will also end up with a situation where you could change things for one compiler, and break compilation settings for the others.

Keeping build settings in header files will also spread your compilation settings to places other than your build system configuration (e.g. Visual Studio property sheets or cmake files) and make everything harder to track, document, follow, and ultimately maintain for the duration of your project.

Long term, **you are probably much better off, cleaning your official build system, than adding hacks to the build, in include files.**

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it is relevant for most branches of software development (and irrelevant for my specific case). Sometimes the build process is essential part of the source code and wrong compilation flag (like optimization -O2 instead of -O3) is equal to an enormous bug in the code and may render the code useless. In order to avoid bugs you expect 100% source code   to reside inside .h/.c/.cpp files or otherwise it will be hard to track the code. The same case is here. If wrong compilation flag introduces a real 'bug' than the flag must be in the same exact place as the code

Comment: In other words, in most cases the source code fully describes the behavior of the program, while build process just converts the source code to specific machine instruction (controlling for some extend the speed and memory usage). But in some cases the source code was designed for a specific build process. So wrong build will still produce an .exe file but may introduce such a severe bug that can render the whole product as useless to the customers.